# Childlessness rate by country

Tags: data-request, historical, demographics

Does anyone know where I can find a table or map of the childlessness rate by country for both men and women? Historical comparison of data would also be desirable.

Comment: census? https://www.census.gov/library/stories/2017/08/more-adults-living-without-children.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a useful table in this document.

[OECD Family Database](https://www.oecd.org/els/family/SF_2-5-Childlessness.pdf)

Comment: Seems like around 10% of women everywhere opt for or can't or don't find the right match for having a child.